# What should our predefined off-topic reasons be?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, on-topic-definition

There are some fairly major changes coming soon to how posts are closed, you may want to read up on the details:

- [Closing changes: [on hold], unclear, too broad, opinion-based, off-topic reasons, bye-bye to Too Localized](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184154/162704)
- [Responding to your “too localized” concerns](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/185102/162704)

We will need to come up with our own list of custom off topic reasons for Programmers. These reasons will be available to close voters after they have picked the generic "off topic" one. Here's a screenshot of Meta Stack Overflow's close dialog, where the new system is already available:

[image]

The "other" option will allow a custom message, when none of the three custom reasons applies:

[image]

If you have an "off topic" reason you'd like to nominate, please post it as an answer. Some general guidelines:

- One reason per answer, so they can be voted separately.
- A brief comment explaining why the general category is off topic is mandatory. See the examples in the first screenshot for inspiration. If we have a *good* Meta discussion explaining in detail why the category doesn't work, please link to it in your comment.
- Examples to existing closed questions that would fit your custom reason would be immensely helpful.
- If there's already an answer with a reason similar to what you have in mind, but with a slightly different phrasing, please consider commenting on the existing answer and refining the phrasing instead of posting a new answer.

---

The winners:

- ["what language, technology, or project one should take up next"](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5994/25936)
- ["career or education advice"](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5993/25936)
- ["recommend a tool, library or favorite off-site resource"](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6025/25936)

Comment: [per recent discussion at MSO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185102/responding-to-your-too-localized-concerns#comment566585_185102), looks like we have like seven: 1) "Workplace" 2) "Stack Overflow" 3) "learn next" 4) "do next" 5) "read next" 6) "career advice" 7) "non-programming activities". These are explicitly listed in "not about..." section of [Help Center > Asking](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Do we also have to provide "off-topic reasons" for migration targets (such as migration to SO for code questions), or will those be added automatically to the list?

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau No, those will be the same as they are today. The screenshot doesn't have migration targets because MSO doesn't have any.

Comment: Is there still going to be a generic off-topic reason for questions that are blatantly off topic such as "How do I change the oil on my car?"

Comment: @AaronKurtzhals Unfortunately no. This was a bit of [a controversial decision](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/185101/162704), and SE said they'll keep an eye on off topic closures and might reconsider if there's a clear need for a generic off topic. There's a feature request asking for [a mod only generic off topic](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185578/can-i-have-a-straight-up-real-off-topic-reason-for-moderators-only) (mod only because a user one had already been declined) but I can't say I'm optimistic about it.

Comment: I see the close reasons have changed now, but none of these are there; rather we have 5 off-topic choices already... Did the decision happen that we don't get to choose our off-topic reasons after all? Or are these going to be added later, at which point, we're going to have a huge amount of off-topic choices... could be a bit cumbersome/annoying

Comment: @JimmyHoffa Moderators can update the close reasons, we can add/edit/remove/sort them at any time. There's a fixed limit of 3 custom reasons, so the list won't get long (unless we explicitly ask for it to be longer). The reasons we have now were picked by SE, mostly for the feature to not roll out empty.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merge and replace custom close reason](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/7721/merge-and-replace-custom-close-reason)

Answer (score 8):

Questions about **what language, technology, or project one should take up next** are off topic on Programmers, as they can only attract subjective opinions for answers. There are too many individual factors behind the question to create answers that will have lasting value. You may be able to get help on [The Whiteboard](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21/the-whiteboard), our chat room.

Comment: I would like to add 'project' as well: "what [language | technology | project ] ..."

Comment: Or even which language/technology is better.

Comment: @Dynamic - I think that's a good suggestion for the shark vs. gorilla close reason.  And yes, that one still needs to be added to the list here.

Comment: rephrase suggestion: Career advice questions, including "What should I do next?" (book/project/language) or "How do I convince someone to do something?" are off topic because they tend to attract opinionated answers.

Comment: @AaronKurtzhals - I'm not opposed to that rephrasing and moving the elements into parenthesis.  The "How do I convince ..." is a separate line of closing and deserves its own entry.

Comment: We can't present multi-choice syntaxes to the green folks who will be posting "I don't know how to program, what language should I learn?". I filled in the blanks to make it as generally meeting all choices as possible, if you don't like my edits roll back or think about how else to phrase this stuff, but bear in mind the audience who will be suffering this message on their questions and what will be of the greatest help to them.

Comment: This is now live. Enjoy, close voters!

Answer (score 7):

Questions seeking **career or education advice** are off topic on Programmers. They are only meaningful to the asker and do not generate lasting value for the broader programming community. Furthermore, in most cases, any answer is going to be a subjective opinion that may not take into account all the nuances of a (your) particular circumstance.

Comment: I'm wondering if the career/professional development related questions can be linked to The Workplace as a suggestion (preferably The Workplace's help page about what is on topic there)? Or would that be equivalent to having a migration path to a beta site (which isn't done)?

Comment: @ThomasOwens - I pondered mixing Workplace into the answer but didn't because it's beta and didn't know what I would be trampling upon... :-)

Comment: I think I prefer your first version. I don't like the opening sentence in this, it reads like we are telling people we don't want their questions because they are too difficult to answer.

Comment: @YannisRizos - tweaked as you suggested.  Might be a bit less friendly to newbies now, but I tried to mollify that by pointing out that random strangers on the internets don't know all the particulars of their issue.

Comment: @GlenH7 Thanks. I moved things around a bit to match the other reasons' phrasing. Hopefully, I didn't completely screw up and this is still parsable.

Comment: This is now live. Enjoy, close voters!

Answer (score 5):

Pitting two large choices against each other doesn't fit the Q&A format well. This question is begging for debate as opposed to information, and the answers will not stand up over time as the choices change. Both options are likely good and bad, try to reformulate this question to as for a solution to your problem and you may get more beneficial responses. For further details why questions like this generate poor quality content read [this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/) by StackExchange's co-founder.

Answer (score 5):

I think you should consider adopting one of Stack Overflow's custom reasons:

> Questions asking us to **recommend a tool, library or favorite off-site resource** are off-topic for Programmers as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

This is (sort of) covered under Too Broad, so I understand if you don't want to use up one of your three slots for this, but it's proven to be very useful on Stack Overflow to call that out specifically.

Comment: This is what I was aiming for with my resource requests off topic one below, but this wording is a little cleaner

Comment: This is now live. Enjoy, close voters!

Answer (score 4):

This question: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/202875/which-technologies-will-most-affect-financial-services-over-the-next-decade

just made me remember another good reason we constantly close stuff, folks asking for a technical crystal ball.

---

This question is asking for pure speculation, of which no one can be provably correct, incorrect, or informative in any way at the present moment. This site has a focus on gathering authoritative content, unfortunately for this question no such content is currently possible.

Answer (score 3):

This is an attempt to begin a discussion, however this is not a discussion forum. This site is for providing authoritative answers to specific questions. Feel free to join The Whiteboard chatroom if you wish to participate in discussion.

Comment: this describes not constructive, not off topic

Comment: @Ryathal Will not constructive still be a close reason after the overhaul is finished?

Comment: sort of, there are going to be 3 reasons replacing not constructive and not a real question, "primarily opinion based" is the closest fit to this, but really this sounds good for its own separate reason not under off topic.

Comment: @Ryathal we don't get to choose new close reasons that aren't under off topic though, and opinion based is a bit of a stretch; open-ended discussion questions can be based completely in an objectively measurable domain

Answer (score 3):

This site is for questions and answers regarding programming specific concepts and activities. Questions that aren't specific to programming or won't be relevant or useful to professional programmers are off topic.

Answer (score 0):

Questions that are not unique to the programming profession are off-topic for Programmers. This question either applies to any profession (try Workplace) or requires expertise in another profession (such as law/business/marketing) for an expert answer.

Comment: I don't like that this makes it seem as though things about the programming profession are on topic where 99% of them are not.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that the existing close reason

> Questions seeking career advice or help with office politics are
>   off-topic here unless they're specific to the programming profession.
>   If people in other professions face similar problems, ask about it on
>   The Workplace Stack Exchange.

Should be changed to

> Questions seeking career advice or help with office politics are
>   off-topic here. For a question about office politics, ask about it on
>   The Workplace Stack Exchange.

Points being

1. My understanding is that career advice and office politics are off-topic here, regardless of whether the career or politics are specific to software development or the programming profession.
2. Career advice is off-topic on The Workplace.

Comment: I believe that existing close reason is one of our "custom" reasons that is going to be changed out once a mod chooses to edit the custom reasons.  So while your suggestion may not take its place, the current phrasing will go away.